# How do I change the value of the y-axis by 30 instead of 10?

Tags: html, json, d3.js, visualization, bar-chart

What I want to put into my chart is that the y-axis value to be like (0,30,60,90,120,150,180,210,230,270) where 0 is the minimum and 270 is the maximum but when I use tickValues(), the number will exceed the y-axis and I cannot see it in the graph. So I would like to be able to decrease the space between the tick values of 0 and 30 so that the maximum value of 270 will be shown in my chart. How would I be able to do it?

```
.bar {
  fill: steelblue;
}

.bar:hover {
  fill: brown;
}

.axis {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}

.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.x.axis path {
  display: black;
}

.d3-tip {
  line-height: 1;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 12px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 2px;
}

/* Creates a small triangle extender for the tooltip */
.d3-tip:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: inline;
  font-size: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 1;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  content: "\25BC";
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
}

/* Style northward tooltips differently */
.d3-tip.n:after {
  margin: -1px 0 0 0;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
}

</style>
<body>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://labratrevenge.com/d3-tip/javascripts/d3.tip.v0.6.3.js"></script>
<script>
var data = [{"countryName":"Afghanistan","gender":"Female","deaths":"97"},
            {"countryName":"Afghanistan","gender":"Male","deaths":"108"}];
var deathArray = data.map(function(d){ return parseInt(d.deaths) });
var opacity = d3.scale.linear()
                .domain([d3.min(deathArray), d3.max(deathArray)])
                .range([0.1,1.0]);

var margin = {top: 100, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 40},
    width = 200;
    height = 200;

var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .rangeRoundBands([0, width], .5);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([height, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom");

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left")

var tip = d3.tip()
  .attr('class', 'd3-tip')
  .offset([-10, 0])
  .html(function(d) {
    return "<strong>Deaths:</strong> <span style='color:red'>" + d.deaths + "</span>";
  })

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

svg.call(tip);

 d3.json("data.json", function(error, data) {
  x.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.gender;}));
  y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.deaths; })]);

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis)
    .append("text")
      .attr("transform", "0")
      .attr("x", 10)
      .attr("dx", ".71em")
      .style("text-anchor", "right")
      .text("2008");

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(yAxis)
    .append("text")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("y", 10)
      .attr("dy", ".71em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .text("Deaths");

  svg.selectAll(".bar")
      .data(data)
    .enter().append("rect")
      .attr("class", "bar")
      .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.gender); })
      .attr("width", x.rangeBand(1))
      .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.deaths); })
          .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.deaths); })
          .on('mouseover', tip.show)
          .on('mouseout', tip.hide)
       .style("opacity",function(d){ return opacity(d.deaths) });

     }); 
    function type(d) {
  d.deaths = +d.deaths;
  return d;
}

</script>
```

[image: Barchart]

Comment: Make it work: http://jsfiddle.net/TDsfL/2/  And then we will see :)

Comment: @Mr.TK My jsfiddle is not working at the moment so could you please try to help me create one?

Comment: That's what I asked You for! :) I don't have time to play with it to make it work and You are the one that created this code, so You have to know what to do to make it work in this fiddle. :) I bet answering your question will be easy but I have to see the working example first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want to have your y axis to go from 0 to 270. You need to make sure that its domain will cover that. So instead of having

```
y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.deaths; })]);
```

you will need to hard code the max value to be 270 like this

```
y.domain([0, 270]);
```

However, if you leave it at that the ticks value will be [0, 20, 40, ..., 260] since d3 will try to pick the best values to display on the axis for you. To meet your needs, you will need to hard code the tick values of the y axis as well, using **.tickValues([data...])**. So something like this

```
var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
.scale(y)
.orient("left")
.tickValues(d3.range(0, 271, 30))
```

what **d3.range(0, 271, 30)** do is create an array of numbers that range from 0 to 271 with steps of 30, which is **[0,30,60,...,270]**

You can see the fixed jsfiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/TDsfL/7/.